# More metrics in Tensorboard

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I create a custom environment for an example of trading bot (RL).

During the training I wanted to check results by using of TensorBoard, but what I see are only a few metrics, in particular only :

```
-----------------------------------------
| time/                   |             |
|    fps                  | 711         |
|    iterations           | 2           |
|    time_elapsed         | 5           |
|    total_timesteps      | 4096        |
| train/                  |             |
|    approx_kl            | 0.011529377 |
|    clip_fraction        | 0.0534      |
|    clip_range           | 0.2         |
|    entropy_loss         | -1.09       |
|    explained_variance   | 0.0319      |
|    learning_rate        | 0.0003      |
|    loss                 | 0.0119      |
|    n_updates            | 10          |
|    policy_gradient_loss | -0.00402    |
|    value_loss           | 0.0277      |
-----------------------------------------
```

according to this (https://medium.com/aureliantactics/understanding-ppo-plots-in-tensorboard-cbc3199b9ba2) I expected more metrics, in particular something about the reward such as `rollout/ep_lean_mean` and `rollout/ep_rew_mean`

this is my code:

```
import gym 
from gym import spaces 
 
class customEnv(gym.Env): 
    """Custom Environment that follows gym interface""" 
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']} 
 
    def __init__(self, df, initial_balance=100, lookback_window_size=50, Render_range=100,): 
        super(customEnv, self).__init__() 
        self.df = df.reset_index() 
        self.fees = .998 
        self.initial_balance = initial_balance 
        self.lookback_window_size = lookback_window_size 
        self.df_total_steps = len(self.df)-1 
        self.orders_history = deque(maxlen=self.lookback_window_size) 
        self.columns = list(self.df.columns[1:]) 
        self.Render_range = Render_range 
        # Market history contains the OHCL values for the last lookback_window_size prices 
        self.market_history = deque(maxlen=self.lookback_window_size) 
        # Define action and observation space 
        # They must be gym.spaces objects 
        # Example when using discrete actions: 
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3) 
        # Example for using image as input: 
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low= -np.inf,high=np.inf, 
                                            shape=(self.lookback_window_size,len(self.columns) + 5), 
                                           dtype= np.float64) 
     
 
    def reset(self,env_steps_size = 0 ):
        #self.visualization = TradingGraph(Render_range=self.Render_range, Show_reward=self.Show_reward, Show_indicators=self.Show_indicators) # init visualization 
        #self.trades = deque(maxlen=self.Render_range) # limited orders memory for visualization 
        #print("RESET")
        self.balance = self.initial_balance 
        self.net_worth = self.initial_balance 
        self.prev_net_worth = self.initial_balance 
        self.crypto_held = 0 
        self.crypto_sold = 0 
        self.crypto_bought = 0 
        self.episode_orders = 0 # track episode orders count 
        self.prev_episode_orders = 0 # track previous episode orders count 
        self.rewards = deque(maxlen=self.Render_range) 
        self.env_steps_size = env_steps_size 
        self.punish_value = 0 
        self.trades = deque(maxlen=self.Render_range) 
        if env_steps_size > 0: # used for training dataset 
            self.start_step = random.randint(self.lookback_window_size, self.df_total_steps - env_steps_size) 
            self.end_step = self.start_step + env_steps_size 
        else: # used for testing dataset 
            self.start_step = self.lookback_window_size 
            self.end_step = self.df_total_steps 
             
        self.current_step = self.start_step 
 
        for i in reversed(range(self.lookback_window_size)): 
            current_step = self.current_step - i 
            self.orders_history.append([self.balance, #/ self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.net_worth,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_bought,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_sold,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_held# / self.normalize_value 
                                        ]) 
 
            # one line for loop to fill market history withing reset call 
            self.market_history.append([self.df.loc[current_step, column] for column in self.columns]) 
             
        state = np.concatenate((self.orders_history, self.market_history), axis=1) 
        #print(f"END RESET: {state.shape} - {np.isnan(state).sum()}")
        return state 
    def step(self, action, production = False): 
        #print("STEP")
        self.crypto_bought = 0 
        self.crypto_sold = 0 
        self.current_step += 1 
 
        # Set the current price to a random price between open and close 
        #current_price = random.uniform( 
        #    self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Open'], 
        #    self.df.loc[self.current_step,'Close']) 
        current_price = self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Open'] 
        Date = self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Date'] # for visualization 
        High = self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'High'] # for visualization 
        Low = self.df.loc[self.current_step, 'Low'] # for visualization 
 
        if action == 0: # Hold 
            pass 
 
        elif action == 1 and self.balance > self.initial_balance*0.05: 
            # Buy with 100% of current balance 
            self.crypto_bought = self.balance / current_price 
            self.crypto_bought *= (1-self.fees) # substract fees 
            self.balance -= self.crypto_bought * current_price 
            self.crypto_held += self.crypto_bought 
            self.trades.append({'Date' : Date, 'High' : High, 'Low' : Low, 'total': self.crypto_bought, 'type': "buy", 'current_price': current_price}) 
            self.episode_orders += 1 
 
        elif action == 2 and self.crypto_held*current_price> self.initial_balance*0.05: 
            # Sell 100% of current crypto held 
            self.crypto_sold = self.crypto_held 
            self.crypto_sold *= (1-self.fees) # substract fees 
            self.balance += self.crypto_sold * current_price 
            self.crypto_held -= self.crypto_sold 
            self.trades.append({'Date' : Date, 'High' : High, 'Low' : Low, 'total': self.crypto_sold, 'type': "sell", 'current_price': current_price}) 
            self.episode_orders += 1 
 
        self.prev_net_worth = self.net_worth 
        self.net_worth = self.balance + self.crypto_held * current_price 
 
        self.orders_history.append([self.balance ,#/ self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.net_worth,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_bought,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_sold,# / self.normalize_value, 
                                        self.crypto_held# / self.normalize_value 
                                        ]) 
 
        # Receive calculated reward 
        reward = self.get_reward() 
 
        if self.net_worth <= self.initial_balance*0.9: 
            done = True 
        else: 
            done = False 
 
        obs = self.next_observation(production) 
        #print(reward,action)
        return obs, reward, done, {} 
     
     # Get the data points for the given current_step 
    def next_observation(self,production): 
        if(not production): 
            self.market_history.append([self.df.loc[self.current_step, column] for column in self.columns]) 
        obs = np.concatenate((self.orders_history, self.market_history), axis=1) 
        return obs 
 
    # Calculate reward 
    def get_reward(self): 
        if self.episode_orders > 1 and self.episode_orders > self.prev_episode_orders: 
            self.prev_episode_orders = self.episode_orders 
            if self.trades[-1]['type'] == "buy" and self.trades[-2]['type'] == "sell": 
                reward = self.trades[-2]['total']*self.trades[-2]['current_price'] - self.trades[-2]['total']*self.trades[-1]['current_price'] 
                self.trades[-1]["Reward"] = reward
                return reward 
            elif self.trades[-1]['type'] == "sell" and self.trades[-2]['type'] == "buy": 
                reward = self.trades[-1]['total']*self.trades[-1]['current_price'] - self.trades[-2]['total']*self.trades[-2]['current_price'] 
                self.trades[-1]["Reward"] = reward 
                return reward
            #elif self.trades[-1]['type'] == "sell" and self.trades[-2]['type'] == "sell": 
            #    return -100
            #elif self.trades[-1]['type'] == "buy" and self.trades[-2]['type'] == "buy": 
            #    return -100
            else:
                return 0
        else: 
            return 0 
 
     
    def render(self, mode='human', close=False): 
        profit = self.net_worth - self.initial_balance 
        print(f'Step: {self.current_step}') 
        print(f'Balance: {self.balance}') 
        print(f'Crypto held: {self.crypto_held}') 
        print(f'Profit: {profit}') 
        # Render the environment to the screen



from stable_baselines3 import A2C,PPO

env.reset()
model = PPO("MlpPolicy",env,verbose= 1,tensorboard_log= logdir)
TIMESTEPS = 10000
for i in range(1,10):
    model.learn(total_timesteps= TIMESTEPS*i,reset_num_timesteps=False,tb_log_name=kind)
    model.save(f"{models_dir}/{TIMESTEPS*i}")
```

how I can show more metrics?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [solution](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/24), the env variable must be incapsulated into Monitor:

```
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
env = Monitor(env, logdir, allow_early_resets=True)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
```

I hope this can help someone